# Angular is creating caches of NPM packages in .angular directory

Tags: angular

How do I disable the angular caching that occurs in the root of all of the Angular projects? This seemed to start last week when I installed NVM.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular now supports the use of persistent build cache by default for new v13 projects.

To disable it you can run below command in your workspace root folder.

```
ng config cli.cache.enabled false
```

You can also disabled it by setting the "enabled" flag to "false" in angular.json file

```
"cli": {
    "cache": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  }
```

Reference:-
https://angular.io/cli/cache

Comment: THANK YOU. I've been searching everywhere to figure this out including Angular docs. Much appreciated.

Comment: @MarkLancaster If this answer your question please mark it as accepted. That will help others as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Vimal Patel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70249096/392895) is accurate, but the following command will do the same without having to know the configuration path ([documentation](https://angular.io/cli/cache#disable)).

```bash
ng cache disable
```

However, disabling the build cache will not prevent npm packages in `node_modules` from being cached. Not only are packages in `node_modules` [considered immutable](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22104#issuecomment-961936785) unless the version in `package.json` changes, webpack also [considers node_modules to be immutable](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22104#issuecomment-961938428).