Angular common library
I have two applications that I want to keep separate, and I want them to share common code. I've tried a few approaches

I made a common library in the same workspace as one of the applications. I noticed that within Visual Studio I could see the applications code in the library. That would get confusing quickly

I made a common library in a different workspace. I then included it via


npm install "file://../../CommonLib/ClientApp/dist/common-lib/main"
but it seems like npm/webpack/angular is looking at the version number to see if the file has changed and not picking up changes during development

I had also previously used npm pack to make a node_module package, but that had the caching issues as well as you would expect

What do I want? I want the same as I have in C#. A common library that can't see the code from the applications in any way, that we can change easily enough and that the applications can use
I have tried AI which suggested adding a unique hash, which seems like a bit of a hack

What about disabling the cache if you have issues with it? ng cache disable

I'm not convinced that will work as reading up on it suggests there's other caches involved, but also isn't that a global measure? There must be a better way
See the comment in the bottom answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70248846/angular-is-creating-caches-of-npm-packages-in-angular-directory

It's per project. ng cache disable will change the angular.json of the current project, while all other projects will still have cache enabled.

I think this answer is wrong. Added a comment there.

That appears to work, but it doubles the build time, which makes sense.. I need to understand exactly what is cached and what side effects this can have (like the pun in your name b.t.w.)

Other than worse performance for subsequent builds, disabling the cache should not have any side effects
